# PowerShell Save-PdfField cmdlet is splitting value into 2 lines

Tags: powershell, pdf, itext

Using this one cmdlet (Save-PdfField) to populate a multiple column NAFTA form one column’s values are being split into two lines.  Line one contains 9 characters and line two contains the 10th character.  However, when i manually type into the editable form, all 10 characters fit on one line.  Also, and this might be unrelated, subsequent opens of the PDF document generate an error related to extended features not available.  No fields are then open for updates.

Every solution i've found that seems to be related references cmdlets that i'm not using.  All other fields seem to populate correctly.  This PDF is a second form (but a separate document) for a continuation of page one.  This initial document has the same field and it does not exhibit the two line problem.  Nor does it generate the extended features error and all fields are available for editing.

Here is some of the cmdlet's code.  Fields "tariffclassX" are the problem fields.

```
$ReturnCode = Save-PdfField -Fields @{descripofgoods1 =    $DescriptionOfGoods1a; `
tariffclass1 = $TariffClass1a; `
origin1 = $Origin1a; `
NetCost1 = $NetCost1a; `
descripofgoods2 = $DescriptionOfGoods2; `
tariffclass2 = $TariffClass2; `
origin2 = $Origin2; `
NetCost2 = $NetCost2;
descripofgoods3 = $DescriptionOfGoods3; `
< ... lines 3 thru 12 omitted ... >
tariffclass13 = $TariffClass13; `
origin13 = $Origin13; `
NetCost13 = $NetCost13} `
-InputPdfFilePath "C:\Temp\NAFTA ATTACH BLANK.PDF" `
-ITextSharpLibrary "C:\Windows\SysWOW64\iTextSharp.5.5.9\lib\itextsharp.dll" `
-OutputPdfFilePath $SupplierPdf
```

Cmdlet "Get-PdfFieldNames returns (in part)

```
F[0].P1[0].descripofgoods1[0]
F[0].P1[0].tariffclass1[0]
F[0].P1[0].preference1[0]
F[0].P1[0].Producer1[0]
F[0].P1[0].origin1[0]
F[0].P1[0].descripofgoods2[0]
F[0].P1[0].tariffclass2[0]
F[0].P1[0].preference2[0]
F[0].P1[0].Producer2[0]
F[0].P1[0].origin2[0]
```

...

Comment: How is this related to iText? Why is this tagged as an iText question??? Are you aware that the fields look like XFA fields rather than AcroForm fields? If you don't understand what XFA and AcroForm fields are, are you sure you know what you're talking about? Please explain.

Comment: Geesh, Mr. Lowagie -- please forgive me for offending you.  It should be painfully obvious that i don't have a clue what i'm talking about.  Yes, i'm in over my head.  That is why i turned to the experts.  iTextSharp was tagged because i had to download DLL's for it before the cmdlets would work and it is referenced in the iTextSharpLibrary parameter.  All i know is that thanks to hits here and elsewhere, i was able to craft code that actually mostly works.